# show dataframe lisibly with python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I create a dataframe from 3 lists and I would like to print it (more like a table).

Hre my code:

for doc1 in source_doc:

```
source_vec = vectorize(doc1)
# print(source_vec) 
for doc in target_docs:
    target_vec = vectorize(doc)

    sim_score = np.dot(source_vec, target_vec) / (np.linalg.norm(source_vec) * np.linalg.norm(target_vec))
    # print("source:", doc1, "target", doc, sim_score)
    # if sim_score >= threshold:
    # if doc1 not in index:                        
    index.append(doc1)
    colonnes.append(doc)
    score.append(sim_score)
```

data = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': index, 'y': colonnes, 'z': score})
print(data)

I don't know if there there is something missing in my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From this code you should get the output three columns (document1, document2, similarity_score), where each of document1, document2 is numpy array

The output for sample row may look like:
[1, 2,...]   ;;   [1, 2,...]   ;;   0.5   (;; is some spacing)

I would recommend to add column names to pd.DataFrame

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':index, 'y':colonnes, 'z':score}, index=['source_document', 'target_document', 'similarity_score'])
```